# Stored procedure's output parameters not updating

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have created a linq2sql project in which I have an extension method for calling SPs.
This extension method has few features-

- It can call SP with Table Valued Parameters.
- It can accepts both input and output parameters
- It will handle multiple result set

Extension Method -

```
public partial class TestLinq2SqlDataContext : DataContext
{
public IMultipleResults ExceuteProcedure(string spName, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters, SqlConnection sqlConnection, out SqlDataReader reader)
{
    reader = null;
    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = sqlConnection,
                CommandText = spName,
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return Translate(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I am calling below SP -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_OutPutParameterCheck(
   @Id int OUTPUT,
   @Name nvarchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET @Id = 12 SET @Name = N'NameSet for OutputParameter'
END
```

My C# code is

```
public static void Main(){
context = new TestLinq2SqlDataContext();

#region USP_OutPutParameterCheck

var connection1 = context.Connection as SqlConnection;
SqlDataReader dataReader1;
var outParam1 = new SqlParameter
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value = "Abc",
    DbType = DbType.String,
    ParameterName = "@Name"
};
var outParam2 = new SqlParameter
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value = 1,
    DbType = DbType.Int32,
    ParameterName = "@Id"
};
var parameters11 = new[]
    {
        outParam1,
        outParam2
    };
var data21 = context.ExceuteProcedure("USP_OutPutParameterCheck", parameters11, connection1, out dataReader1);
}
```

Now When I check the values of output parameters in debug mode I am getting the `@Id`'s value perfect 
but for `@Name` parameter I'm only getting **'N'** value instead of **'NameSet for OutputParameter'**

Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong in this?

Thanks

UPDATE :

Adding Screenshot when seeing the values of parameters in debug mode -
[image: debug mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You must specifcy the Size of the outParam1.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.size(v=vs.110).aspx

> For bidirectional and output parameters, and return values, you must
>   set the value of Size. This is not required for input parameters, and
>   if not explicitly set, the value is inferred from the actual size of
>   the specified parameter when a parameterized statement is executed.